# jsonp , WCF bad request error

Tags: jquery, wcf, jsonp

I have a WCF service returning data in json format, however I am forced to use jsonp with jquery due to the Access control allow origin, the problem is that jsonp adds a callback function to the URL passed to retrieve the json data and this results in a bad request, I am wondering is there any way on the server-side to tell it to ignore any callback functions which are passed through the URL or some quick fix to this problem short of reprogramming the server altogether.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716898.aspx) is sample describing how to work with JSONP in WCF. Might be you need to add next files in your project.

```
JSONPBehavior.cs
JSONPBindingElement.cs
JSONPBindingExtension.cs
JSONPEncoderFactory.cs
```